# I'm stuck with vscode flutter emulator

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, emulation

I Cannot find any Android devices to connect or an emulator in vs. code, even though I have installed Android Studio.

I tried reinstalling Android studio, but still i can't connect with any devices. it shows no devices, but when I installed it first, I did see pixel vers. 3 or some other emulator.